# Diophantine Equation with 2017th powers: $a^{2017}+a-2=(a-1)(b^{11})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

This problem stems from a recent student-created olympiad contest.

Find all integer (not simply positive) solutions to $a^{2017}+a-2=(a-1)(b^{11})$.

My multiple attempts modulo many small primes suggests that modulo arithmetic if it works will require an extremely contrived approach. I will note that (mod 23) did not work as expected. Furthermore note that $a=1$ is always a solution. (NOTE: There was an error in the problem statement that I didn't initially notice.)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts? What have you tried, and what background results do you know?

Comment: Is the olympiad contest still ongoing???

Comment: The olympiad contest ended a while ago.

Comment: If thre is no solution for $a=1$.to say 10, then we would have almost  $a^{2017}= b^{11}$

Comment: More strictly we have $((a^{2017}-1)+(a-1))/(a-1)=b^{11}$ so that $(a^{2016}¨+a^{2015}+…+1)+1=b^{11}$ and $b^{11}=2$ (mod a)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so $a=1$ is one solution.  We wish to show there are no others, using the hint in your problem.

Hint: first, solve for $b^{11}$, in terms of $a$.  Changing my answer to account for the error you corrected, you would have:

$a^{2016}+\cdots+a^2+a^1+1+1 = b^{11}$

Second, reduce (mod 23).  Let $c=a^{-1}$.  You should get the equation 
$b^{11}=\frac{a^{2017}-1}{a-1} + 1= \frac{a^{-7}-1}{a-1} +1= \frac{c^7-1}{1/c-1}+1=-c(c^6+c^5+c^4+c^3+c^2+c+1)+1 =$
$= 1-(c^7+c^6+c^5+c^4+c^3+c^2+c)$

But, since $(b^{11})^2 = b^{22} \equiv b^0 = 1$ (mod 23), then $b^{11}$ is always either 1 or -1.

Then, just check all values of the LHS (mod 23) to see that this has no solution (mod 23).  They are, in order from $a=1$ to $a=23$:

[this calculation was apparently wrong]

None of these are congruent to 1 or -1 (mod 23), and thus you get that there are no solutions for $a$.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. The LHS and RHS of the equation are the same (mod 7) when a=2,b=5 and therefore (mod 7) is likely not a viable approach.

Comment: Yeah, I miscalculated RHS.  I'll try again.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for not telling me that you changed the problem.  I almost got a second answer, when I realized you changed the problem.  My answer should be complete now.

Comment: Can you explain your reduction mod 23? There appears to be an error.

Comment: What do you mean?  An error where?

Comment: We know that $b$:=$a^{22}+\cdots+a^2+a^1$ satisfies $ba = a$; so $b = 0$.  So we can remove any 22 consecutive terms in the summation, without affecting the total sum.

Comment: Taking a=17 and b=5 both sides of the equation are -1 (mod 23). So there is an error in your approach.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I doublechecked, and yes there was an error.  I removed the erroneous part; I would retry this calculation (mod 67) to see if that would work.  For that, the simplification is a bit easier.  The problem is, the 2017 and 11 are two powers that are making everything hard.  The only prime numbers mod which 2017 is congruent to 1 are, 2, 3, 7.  On the other hand, mod phi(2), phi(3), and phi(7), 11 is congruent to +/- 1.  For this reason, no "clean" solution is possible, only the trial-of-all-numbers ones.  For those, you have to pick a prime that is congruent to 1 (mod 11*2);

Comment: in that case, there are only a few solutions of $b^{11}$ (mod that prime), and so a large probability that none of the powers will match up.

Comment: For one thing, $b^{22}$ is not necessarily $1$ mod $23$. If $23$ divides $b$, then $b^{22}$ is $0$ mod $23$.

Comment: Right.  But, there's still a limited number of choices for $b^{11}$: either -1, 0, or 1.  In the p=67 case, there will be 7 choices for $b^{11}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some progress. I'm afraid it's probably not farther than you have already explored.

Throughout, it is important to know that $11$th powers mod $23$ can only be $-1,0$, or $1$.

Of course, $a=1$ gives a solution. If $a\neq1$, it is OK to divide by $a-1$, giving you

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{2016}a^k+1&=b^{11}\\
\end{align}$$

If $23\mid a$, then the equation reduces to $2\equiv b^{11}$, but that equation has no solution mod $23$.

If $23\not\mid a$, then 
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2002}^{2016}a^k+\sum_{m=0}^{90}\sum_{n=0}^{21}a^{22m+n}+1&=b^{11}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{14}a^k+91\sum_{n=0}^{21}a^{n}+1&\equiv b^{11}\mod{23}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{14}a^k-\sum_{n=0}^{21}a^{n}+1&\equiv b^{11}\mod{23}\\
-{\sum_{n=15}^{21}a^{n}}+1&\equiv b^{11}\mod{23}\\
-a^{15}\sum_{n=0}^{6}a^{n}+1&\equiv b^{11}\mod{23}\\
\end{align}$$
If $a\equiv1$, the equation reduces to $-6\equiv b^{11}$, which again has no solution mod $23$. If $a\not\equiv1$, then
$$\begin{align}
-a^{15}\frac{a^7-1}{a-1}+1&\equiv b^{11}\mod{23}\\
\end{align}$$
It's a bit tedious, but we can evaluate the left side for $a\equiv2,3,\ldots22$. The left side never works out to be $1$ or $-1$. It can be $0$ though for $a\equiv11$ or $a\equiv15$.

So $23\mid b$ and $a\equiv11$ or $a\equiv15$ mod $23$. I didn't find a way to leverage this into more help though. The best I could see from here is that even the smallest (in absolute value) option for $a$, which is $-8$, would imply an enormous (probably noninteger) value for $b$ with $166$ digits. This is somewhat clear from the original equation though, once you eliminate smaller options for $a$ directly.